# How to use Notify.js

Tags: jquery

Please give me a Notify.js example with its file dependencies and sample code.

```
$('#btnclick').click(function () {
  // alert('Button Clicked');
  $.notify("Notify");
});
```

This code is giving me an error.

and error is uncaught typeerror: $.notify is not a function

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/notify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnClick').click(function () {
          $.notify("Notify Messege");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" name="click" value="Show Messege" id="btnClick" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is the error? All you need to know is in their documentation: https://notifyjs.com/. You most likely haven't included jQuery or the notifi JS file properly.

Comment: I have added the files correctly ...if possible help me with simple example

Comment: That error means that you haven't added the files correctly. Please add your HTML to the question

Comment: okay wait for a min .I really need ur help

Comment: Assuming the file paths are correct then the problem is most likely because your version of jQuery is very very old - almost 10 years out of date. Change it to at least 1.12

Comment: Thank u man I got it

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I added the fix as an answer for you.

Comment: @Akki I am having the same problem, could give a step by step procedure? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file paths are correct then the problem is most likely because your version of jQuery is very, very old - almost 10 years out of date.

You should upgrade jQuery to at least version 1.12, preferably 3.2 if you don't need to support IE8 and lower.